# Query correction needed

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
select stdcode,name,degree_code,phone,startsemester,endsemester
from  (                   
         select distinct stdcode as stdcode,name as name,degree_code as degree_code,phone as phone,
              (
                SELECT sem_code
                FROM V_ALLSTUDATA b
                WHERE  a.name = b.name 
                and a.stdcode= b.stdcode 
                and a.degree_code=b.degree_code 
                and a.phone=b.phone
                AND  startsem=(select min(startsem) 
                               from V_ALLSTUDATA b)    
             ) as startsemester,
             (
                SELECT sem_code
                FROM V_ALLSTUDATA b
                WHERE  a.name = b.name 
                and a.stdcode= b.stdcode 
                and a.degree_code=b.degree_code 
                and a.phone=b.phone
                AND  startsem=(select 
                               max(startsem) from V_ALLSTUDATA a)
              ) as endsemester

                from V_ALLSTUDATA a
             );
```

I want to select `sem_code` as `startsem_code` and `sem_code` as `lastsem_code`

How can I fix this error?

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>   01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

[DATA ATTACHED HERE YOU CAN DOWNLOAD FOR YOU CONVENIENCE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uJLxV-0c292etblVn9jI9YpLu_KIvOC9)

Comment: Hi Naseed, is it possible that in view V_ALLSTUDATA, we have many rows satisfying the subqueries for startsemester or endsemester. If not, a distinct in front of sem_code should suffice

Comment: Nobody in their right mind will download and unzip a file from the internet. If you don't want to include the DDL and DML in your question you should post a demo on a site like [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2)

Comment: actually bro i dont knw how to properly post on stackoverflow i just posting second time

Comment: would you halp me plz kindly if possible?

Comment: You already have three answers which explain the cause of the error and how to tackle it (i.e. you need to re-write your query). What further help do you need?

Comment: Do LEFT JOIN's instead.

Comment: thanks to all of you now i got point.. and i learnd a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you got multiple rows in the single query so I think you will be use rownum. 
so Try Below Query

```
select stdcode,name,degree_code,phone,startsemester,endsemester
        from  (                   
                select distinct stdcode as stdcode,name as name,degree_code as degree_code,phone as phone,
              (
                SELECT sem_code
                      FROM V_ALLSTUDATA b
                      WHERE  a.name = b.name and a.stdcode= b.stdcode and a.degree_code=b.degree_code 
 and a.phone=b.phone
                     AND  startsem=(select min(startsem) from V_ALLSTUDATA b where rownum=1)

                    ) as startsemester,
                    (select sem_code
                      from V_ALLSTUDATA b
                       where  a.name = b.name and a.stdcode= b.stdcode and a.degree_code=b.degree_code and a.phone=b.phone
                      and endsem=(select max(startsem) from V_ALLSTUDATA a where rownum=1)

                    ) as endsemester

                from V_ALLSTUDATA a

             );
```

Comment: Will return _one_ result, but perhaps not the result OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Because the subqueries have an explicit requirement that they match `min(startsem)` or `max(startsem)`, I believe that the subqueries will return only one value.  However, they ***may*** return multiple instances of the same value.

To protect against that, I think you want to add `distinct` to both subqueries, like this:

```
            (select distinct sem_code
              from V_ALLSTUDATA b
               where  a.name = b.name and a.stdcode= b.stdcode and a.degree_code=b.degree_code and a.phone=b.phone
              and endsem=(select max(startsem) from V_ALLSTUDATA a)

            ) as endsemester
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in one (or both) `SELECT` statements that return `startsemester` and `endsemester` values. For example:

```
(SELECT sem_code
 FROM V_ALLSTUDATA b
 WHERE     a.name = b.name
   AND a.stdcode = b.stdcode
   AND a.degree_code = b.degree_code
   AND a.phone = b.phone
   AND startsem = (SELECT MIN (startsem)
                   FROM V_ALLSTUDATA b)) AS startsemester
```

It **must not** return more than a single value. As we don't have your data, we can't answer *why* you got `too_many_rows`. There are a few ways out, e.g.

- use one of aggregates, such as `MAX`, e.g. `select max(sem_code) from ...`
- see whether `distinct` helps, e.g. `select distinct sem_code from ...`
- include `rownum` into the `where` clause, e.g. `... and rownum = 1`

but - from my point of view - you should research what causes the error and fix it appropriately. Perhaps you missed some more conditions in the `where` clause; who knows? We don't, you might.

Answer (score 0):

```
     with tt AS
    ( select    f.stdcode,
             f.name,
             f.degree_code,
             f.phone,
             MIN(f.startsem)as startsemdate,
             MAX(f.startsem)as endsemedate
    FROM V_GRADUATED f
    GROUP BY 
      f.stdcode,
      f.name,
      f.degree_code,
      f.phone)
    select    tt.stdcode,
      tt.name,
      tt.degree_code,
      tt.phone,
      (select sem_code 
             from v_graduated a
            where a.stdcode=tt.stdcode 
             and a.startsem=tt.startsemdate) startsemester,
      (select sem_code
             from v_graduated a
             where a.stdcode=tt.stdcode 
            and a.startsem=tt.endsemedate) endsemester
      from tt
```

this is what i was want .......> THIS IS CORRECT ANSWER

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Ahr.png)